# How can I find the index of the last item in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, parameters

**My Array:**

```
(rdb:381) pp params[:payments]
{"0"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/27/2008"},
 "1"=>{":amount_paid"=>"80.00", ":date_paid"=>"3/27/2008"},
 "2"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"5/8/2008"}}
```

I don't believe this is an **object** . Performing `params[:payments].last` returns this :

```
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `last' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x1065e8448>
```

I am trying to find the index of that last item. In this case, the answer is **2**, or **"2"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey, your array is actually a hash.  You could maybe get the index of the last key by doing something like `params[:payments].keys.map(&:to_i).max.to_s`

It would be even better to pass an actual array back.  How are you generated the `:payments` option?

Comment: WOW! I seriously never knew the difference btween hashes and arrays until now. Thank you so much for this!!

Answer (score 0):

Your value is a Hash, not an Array, so it doesn't have ordering or indexes, unless you are on Ruby 1.9

Comment: "Hash has ordering since 1.9" To clarify, hashes maintain their insertion order not a sorted order. From the [Hash docs](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Hash): "Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted."